# Is there any way to tell TDS not to sync security settings field for Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5, tds

Is there any way for me to tell TDS to not sync the __Security field when I do a Sync With Sitecore operation?  I think I can do that for each and every item.  However I was wondering if there was some sort of global setting somewhere.

Corey

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible via the  TDS Options in the Visual Studio Options. You need to go to Tools -> Options -> TDS Options -> Sync Window. There you are presented with an option to exclude fields from syncing. I added an image for reference:

[image: TDS Sync]

Comment: Yeah I saw that.  When I read that dialog box the way I interpreted that was that the Sync With Sitecore window will simply not flag those as being different.  So you won't get your Sync window cluttered up with a lot of stuff that you don't care about.  However it will still sync those field values - it's just not showing those as being different to make your screen easier to read.  Am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: Oh sorry. I misunderstood your question. Yes you are correct. The problem is that TDS is using the generic Sitecore Serialization. I don`t think there is a way to achieve what you want, but you can ask or make a feature request here - support@hhogdev.com  :)

Comment: The problem is that we have different security roles in our DEV environment from our PRODUCTION environment.  So every time we deploy templates from DEV to PROD the security settings on the individual fields are getting overwritten in PROD.

Comment: As a workaround, is there any way that you can use role-based security settings and just change the role definitions in the environments so that your items are the same?